# aws secretsmanager list-secrets --region us-east-1 no rsponde

Tags: aws

Estoy ejecutando el comando

`aws secretsmanager list-secrets --region us-east-1`

y no responde, se queda pegado, que puede ser ?

Comment: Deberías revisar si tus credentials de AWS te permiten acceder al Secret Manager (o si tienes credentials cargadas). Te recomendaría (en caso de tener profiles configurados) indicar el profile en el commando: aws secretsmanager list-secrets --region us-east-1 --profile foo-bar.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa bien que estes usando las credenciales correctas y que tengas los permisos necesarios en IAM para listar los secrets.

Puedes usar --debug para obtener más información.

Comment: Como respuesta se podría detallar más, analizando errores comunes y formas de encontrar los errores. Ya que en la pregunta no hay muchos detalles (y debería tenerlos) sería bueno aclararlos por medio de comentarios en la pregunta del autor.